# Move image smoothly on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I am moving an inserted image within a Canvas.

HTML

```
 <div id="left">move left</div>
```

jQuery:

```
let MoveLeft=0;
$("#left").on("click", function(){
    MoveLeft+=10;
});
```

In the canvas function

```
function(){
    .....
    var LeftPos=100; //default
    If(MoveLeft!=0)
        LeftPos=LeftPos + MoveLeft;
}
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,imgW,imgH,LeftPos,0,imgW,imgH);
```

This works, but the movement takes place in a single jump. How do I translate the image smoothly? Like an animation?

```js
let GlassesUp = 0;
$('.MoveGlasses').on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("MoveGlassesUp")) {

    GlassesUp += 10;

  }
  drawMe();
});

var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// core drawing function
var drawMe = function() {
  var ImgGlasses = document.getElementById('glasses');
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 400;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var GUp = 50;

  if (GlassesUp != 0) {

    GUp = GUp - GlassesUp;
    //alert(GUp)
  }

  ctx.drawImage(ImgGlasses, 0, 0, 250, 250, 50, GUp, 250, 250);
}

drawMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MoveGlasses MoveGlassesUp">Up</div>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126514.svg" style="height:60px;width:100px;opacity:0" id="glasses" />
```

Comment: maybe do what cartoons do, increase frame rate, I mean move slowly & trick eyes into believing its moving smoothly

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: can add your complete code in question with its current working

Comment: Use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and its callback argument in tandem with [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

Comment: @vinayakj here there is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/8/

Comment: @Xufox how would you apply this `requestAnimationFrame` in this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/8/

Comment: @joe, is this something that you want https://jsfiddle.net/vinayakjadhav/vf8gvq7m/18/

Comment: Ok. In  this case after clicking on  `up` the glasses moves upwards indefinitely. How to stop the set interval?

Comment: whenever you want

Comment: What do you mean..

Comment: using `clearInterval` function, check the answer below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167586/discussion-between-vinayakj-and-joe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The draw function displaces the image by 0.7 per 100ms. You can adjust these two parameters.

```js
let GlassesUp = 0;
var t;
$('.MoveGlassesUp').on("click", function(event) {
clearInterval(t)
  t = setInterval(function() {
    GlassesUp += 0.7;
    drawMe();
  }, 100);
  setTimeout("clearInterval(t)", 1000)
});

$('.MoveGlassesDown').on("click", function(event) {
clearInterval(t)
  t = setInterval(function() {
    GlassesUp -= 0.7;
    drawMe();
  }, 100);
  setTimeout("clearInterval(t)", 1000)
});



var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// core drawing function
var drawMe = function() {
  var ImgGlasses = document.getElementById('glasses');
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 400;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var GUp = 50;


  if (GlassesUp != 0) {

    GUp = GUp - GlassesUp;
    //alert(GUp)
  }

  ctx.drawImage(ImgGlasses, 0, 0, 250, 250, 50, GUp, 250, 250);






}


drawMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="MoveGlasses MoveGlassesUp">up</button>
<button class="MoveGlasses MoveGlassesDown">down</button>
<hr/>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>

<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126514.svg" style="height:60px;width:100px;opacity:0" id="glasses" />
```

Comment: It works...but not the way is needed. At the end it will be 4 arrows (top,left,right,bottom) to allocate the position of the glasses within the canvas. So 8 buttons to stop them....

Comment: It has to be an animation

Comment: button is not needed per say, just stop after some fixed displacement if you want.. just use clearInterval function based on your condition of stop

Comment: What about a canvas function? Not jquery related?

Comment: plz check updated answer, added up & down buttons which displaces image for 1s & then stop.

Comment: Old school animation...its much more better...I liked this one, the problem here is if you click repeated times on a same button, the glasses go on that direction unstopable. Maybe an .off()? Idk.

Comment: Ok. This is want I was talking about. Finally you convinced me. Ill add this code to mine. Answer marked!.